# Multiple Sources directories using maven-remote-resources-plugin

Tags: maven

I am trying to use maven-remote-resources-plugin to bundle resources from one of my projects. The problem I have is that i wish to bundle resources from two different locations:

```
src/main/java/es/ws/handler.xml
src/main/resources/myResources/*
```

I could do something like this

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-remote-resource.version}</version>
     <executions>
      <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>bundle</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         <resourcesDirectory>${basedir}/src</resourcesDirectory>
         <includes>
         <include>**/myResources/**</include>
         <include>**/handler.xml</include>
         </includes> 
     </configuration>
     </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

but this would export me the resources in the following manner

```
main/java/es/ws/handler.xml
main/resources/myResources/image.png
main/resources/myResources/novel.txt
```

and I would like them

```
handler.xml
myResources/image.png
myResources/novel.txt
```

So my question is: Is there a way to define multiple resourcesDirectory in order to select each folder separately and avoid having the full path

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 execution block, each with a unique id. Use one block for the handler, the other for the myResources.
However, since you use ${basedir}, I think you actually want to use the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)
See also http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add more than one resource then you have to add another block of resources `<execution>`. Here is a complete sample.

```
               <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/../frontend/build</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Then if you need to add a specific file than add like the following.

```
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-index-page</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/templates
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/../frontend/build</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>index.html</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```